# Clouddrive mount issue

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-cli, azure-clouddrive

I am trying to change the clouddrive location to another storage account so that I can map it on my computer and upload files directly to it. I am running the following command in azure cli:

clouddrive mount -s subscriptionID -g Resource Group -n storageaccountname -f filesharename

But I am getting this error:

```
ERROR: Failed to update storage profile. Response: {
  "error": {
    "code": "UserSettingsNetworkTypeInvalid",
    "message": "The user settings network type '<null>' is invalid. The value must be one of 'Isolated,Default'."
  }
}
```

I have looked it up but can't seem to find anything related to this error. Have anyone dealt with this before?

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to reproduce your error. Do note that if you mount an existing file share, the storage accounts must be located in your selected Cloud Shell region. Also, Azure Files supports only locally redundant storage and geo-redundant storage accounts.

Comment: I also opened a ticket before and they told me it's an issue which is being processed. And it should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comment, I eventually opened a ticket with MS and they had the same issue, a workaround for this is to unmount (`cluddrive unmount`)the drive and then reopen Azure CLI, that way you get prompted to set up the clouddrive storage again.

Bear in mind that once you do this, you wont be able to get your command history back, even you revert back to the old storage account.

Another thing I discovered in this journey is that if you go to your storage account and navigate to your fileshare `clouddrive/.cloudconsole` you can upload files there and they will be available on your console under `clouddrive/.cloudconsole`.